# Appending bits to a file in C

Tags: c, io

I'm working on a CRC32 program for a project and I've hit another stumbling block. We get a 32-bit UINT back from the ASM code we have, and in order to test the algorithm, we need to append those exact bits to the end of the text file we threw into the algorithm, and we're kind of at a loss of how to do that. We tried fprint, but that transformed the int into a char and changed the bits. Same deal with fwrite. Is there some way to do this with fwrite we're missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you call `fwrite`?

Comment: @JoeDF Fputc seems to do chars, again, same problem.

Comment: @KeithThompson I don't have it. I'm posting this for one of my teammates whose english is not very good. Yes, I know it sounds stupid, that's what I told her.

Comment: Appending a 32-bit unsigned integer to a file is ambiguous. *How* do those 32 bits need to be appended? A 4 8-bit bytes? In what order? We can't help without knowing your requirements.

Comment: Well, I'm running CRC32, so basically what I have is a series of bits that need to be appended without any flips to the end of the file. As bytes works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have to open the file in binary mode.

It's also possible you have to flip the bytes (if the ASM code returns them in a different endianness than expected. If the target is big-endian, than htonl will work).